# Properties of event horizon for incoming matter

Tags: general-relativity

In one of his lecture,Prof. Susskind mentioned that the event horizon "bulges" forward to meet any incoming radiation or matter; and it is a property of Einstein field equations. I have not come across any such property, and if it exists, shouldn't it belong to the Schwarzchild metric rather?
Please explain me that property in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The Schwarzschild metric is a time independant solution that describes a completely static black hole i.e. one that has existed unchanged for an infinite time in the past and will exist unchanged for an infinite time into the future. It cannot describe anything that is time dependant, like infalling matter, though it may be a useful starting point for a perurbative calculation.

However any perturbations in a real (non-rotating) black hole will decay by emission of gravitational radiation and the black hole will asymptotically approach the Schwarzschild geometry.

So if any matter falls into a black hole we would expect the horizon to be perturbed in some way as the matter falls through it, then relax back to approximately Schwarzschild geometry. Your question boils down to what is the nature of the temporary perturbation.

There is no anayltical solution to describe infalling matter, so the only resort is a numerical calculation. After quite prolonged Googling I cannot find any such calculations for ordinary matter falling into a black hole, but I did find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1668v1) describing calculations of the shape of the event horizon for two merging black holes. You do indeed get a bulge in the horizons as the two black holes approach, and the bulges merge to form a neck before the black holes fully merge and form an (approximately) Kerr black hole.

Comment: You can do perturbation theory, by linearizing around a Schwarzschild or Kerr background, and the back reaction will show a bulging horizon.  The math is truly nightmarish, however.  If my memory is right, Chandrasekhar's book does a bunch of this analysis.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer, can you give me a link to this calculation on the internet?

Comment: @GRrocks: [The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Theory-Classic-Physical-Sciences/dp/0198503709) chapter 4. Good luck! :-)

Comment: The book's really cool....Thanx John Rennie